# How to get diagnostic information through dotnet monitor endpoints. dotnet monitor and testapp pods have different namespaces, mounted to host volume

Tags: kubernetes, namespaces, docker-volume

I have to fetch diagnostic information by triggering dotnet monitor endpoints for some pods containing dotnet applications. Both dotnet monitor and dotnet applications pod are running in separate pod. Say dotnet monitor with namespace "namespace-dotnet-monitor" and application pods with namespaces "namespace-testapp1", "namespace-testapp2".

All the three pods are connected through the same host volume. I can read write through that volume across pods with different namespaces but the dotnet monitor is not able to generate the result as it does if I use the same namespace.

I am providing the code for dotnet monitor pod and the dotnet application pods.

Code for dotnet monitor pod:

```
# Tell us about your experience using dotnet monitor: https://aka.ms/dotnet-monitor-survey
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: n-dotnet-monitor-deploy-ap3
  namespace: namespace-dotnet-monitor
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: n-dotnet-monitor-ap3
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: n-dotnet-monitor-ap3
    spec:
      automountServiceAccountToken: false
      restartPolicy: Always
      containers:
      - name: monitor
        image: mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/monitor
        # DO NOT use the --no-auth argument for deployments in production; this argument is used for demonstration
        # purposes only in this example. Please continue reading after this example for further details.
        args: [ "collect", "--no-auth" ]
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        env:
        - name: DOTNETMONITOR_DiagnosticPort__ConnectionMode
          value: Listen
        - name: DOTNETMONITOR_Storage__DefaultSharedPath
          value: /diag
        # ALWAYS use the HTTPS form of the URL for deployments in production; the removal of HTTPS is done for
        # demonstration purposes only in this example. Please continue reading after this example for further details.
        - name: DOTNETMONITOR_Urls
          value: http://+:52323
        # The metrics URL is set in the CMD instruction of the image by default. However, this deployment overrides that with the args setting; manually set the URL to the same value using configuration.
        - name: DOTNETMONITOR_Metrics__Endpoints
          value: http://+:52325
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /diag
          name: diagvol3
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: 50m
            memory: 32Mi
          limits:
            cpu: 250m
            memory: 256Mi
      volumes:
        - name: diagvol3
          hostPath:
            path: /tmp/
```

Code for testapp pod1:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: n-testapp1-deploy-ap3
  namespace: namespace-testapp1
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: n-testapp1-ap3
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: n-testapp1-ap3
    spec:
      restartPolicy: Always
      containers:
        - name: n-test-app1-ap3
          image: mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/samples:aspnetapp
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          env:
          - name: DOTNET_DiagnosticPorts
            value: /diag/dotnet-monitor.sock
          - name: ASPNETCORE_URLS
            value: http://+:102
          ports:
            - containerPort: 102
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /diag
              name: diagvol3
          resources:
            limits:
              cpu: 250m
              memory: 512Mi
        - name: n-test-app1-2-ap3
          image: mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/samples:aspnetapp
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          env:
          - name: DOTNET_DiagnosticPorts
            value: /diag/dotnet-monitor.sock
          - name: ASPNETCORE_URLS
            value: http://+:103
          ports:
            - containerPort: 103
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /diag
              name: diagvol3
          resources:
            limits:
              cpu: 250m
              memory: 512Mi
      volumes:
        - name: diagvol3
          hostPath:
            path: /tmp/
---
```

Code for testapp pod2:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: n-testapp2-deploy-ap3
  namespace: namespace-testapp2
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: n-testapp2-ap3
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: n-testapp2-ap3
    spec:
      restartPolicy: Always
      containers:
        - name: n-test-app2-ap3
          image: mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/samples:aspnetapp
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          env:
            - name: DOTNET_DiagnosticPorts
              value: /diag/dotnet-monitor.sock
            - name: ASPNETCORE_URLS
              value: http://+:101
          ports:
            - containerPort: 101
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /diag
              name: diagvol3
          resources:
            limits:
              cpu: 250m
              memory: 512Mi
      volumes:
        - name: diagvol3
          hostPath:
            path: /tmp/
```